# Why Javascript's every method is overpowered?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops, benchmarking

I've made benchmark to check performance of few methods of iterating through array.

https://jsperf.com/extended-array-loops-performance

Can someone explain why `every` method is so powered? It's totally weird that it's over 90% faster than any other method, even than those similar to it

Comment: Because it quits as soon as it encounters something false which is opposite of `some` which is really slow.

Comment: Where is `reduce`!? The most underrated array method

Answer (score 6):

Because you're only running it once.

`every()` will loop through elements until it finds a falsey value, at which point it will return.

Since your benchmark doesn't return anything, that is `undefined`, which is `falsey` so it only runs once. All of your other loops run through all of the elements.

Change your test to something like:

```
arr.every(val => {
  sth = val;
  return true;
});
```

And it should fall in line with the rest.